# how to Disable Default Keyboard handling in the Windows Forms DataGridView control in c# framework 4.7

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm using 4.7 .NetFramework. I'm Trying to Press F3 on DataGridView Control and it takes as Sorting GridData. So i want to disable this Key.

Answer (score 1):

The sort mode for each text box column is specified through the `SortMode` property of the column. By default is set to `Automatic`. That why press F3 worked. Set `SortMode` property to `NotSortable` value.

```
dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

More information look at [DataGridViewColumnSortMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode?view=netframework-4.8) and [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/column-sort-modes-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control).

Comment: This is just a work around. What if the OP wants to sort de column , but using F2?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own customized datagridview.

```
class MyDataGridView:DataGridView  
{
      protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
      {
         //Here you have to manage what you want to do with the keys.
      }
}
```